# Lubuntu terminal How to set Proxy

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

The system `Lubuntu 14.*` with terminal not working command 
`gksudo apt-get update`.

I set proxy on `/etc/environment`:

```
http_proxy=http://192.168.10.7:3128/
https_proxy=http://192.168.10.7:3128/
ftp_proxy=http://192.168.10.7:3128/
```

and set proxy for terminal in file `/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh`:

```
export http_proxy="http://192.168.10.7:3128"
export https_proxy="https://192.168.10.7:3128"
```

but all the same not working. Screen error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For apt use /etc/apt/apt.conf file with something like :

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://192.168.10.7:3128/";
Acquire::https::proxy "http://192.168.10.7:3128/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "http://192.168.10.7:3128/";
```